# How to speed up the bootstrap of WebView in my Activity?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am currently developing an app with many HTML pages to render.
The problem is that Android took about 500ms to start a WebView in my Activity.

i.e.:

1. I clicked some Button to trigger an WebView to render, in a new Activity.
2. Android opened another Activity, took about 100ms
3. Android opened a WebView control, took about 300~500ms.
4. This WebView starts to load the URL as usual and render the web content.

My question is: how to reduce the bootstrap time for opening a new WebView?  ( the step2, but not step 3)

As a comparison, IOS bootstraps the WebView immediately, i.e.: 10ms

Comment: Android WebView is **slow**, by nature. Also bear in mind that Java is significantly slower than C. Therefore, a comparison with iOS is out of place.

Comment: @Rotwang Who mentioned C? iOS would likely use Objective-C or Swift, which is arguably comparable in speed to Java, right? Besides the JVM overhead, I suppose.

Comment: @cricket_007 C, Objective C... isn't it quite the same? I'm not aware of this "Swift" thing, though. I thought all iOS apps were written in **Objective** C.

Comment: @Rotwang Objective-C is a layer over C, yes, and Swift was introduced as "Objective-C without the C" around 2 years ago and somewhat looks like Scala code. Anyways, regarding the question, I'm not sure I understand your statement "slow, by nature". Are you saying any WebView on an Android app is slow?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. WebViews aren't optimized at all and they do an awful lot of work. Imagine a TextView, but able to parse ALL the HTML tags, CSS, JavaScript, (I guess they also display animated GIFs correctly? must try) ... but not Flash, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable all the animation and transition in your app as it makes it slower.
2. Try not to render too many requests in your controller and pass objects between them instead.
3. If you are going to show and hide elements according to the result from the database result make all the elements hidden first and then apply visibility then
4. Use services(directives , etc...) and minimize the code in your controller (they aren't supposed to hold too many code in them )

Comment: I am not asking how to optimize the "webview's render speed", but I am asking how to speed up the "bootstrap of webview".